# delete mysql records of a table after a minute

Tags: php, mysql

I need help for a simple question ,

```
$tme = date("Y-m-j H:i:s");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM PM_TABLE WHERE date <= $time - INTERVAL 60 SECOND");
```

So, It should work and delete all records old as long as long 1 minute.

But it cannot do the operation.

returning value would be like this :\

```
DELETE FROM PM_TABLE WHERE date <= 2011-07-28 08:49:29 - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
```

table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PM_TABLE` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: It is usually good idea to let PHP do as much work as you can instead of MySql if they have close execution speed as MySql is usually much harder to scale then PHP. And try to always escape field/table names with "backtick" as you can get some unexpected results with exotic(reserved) names. Just do $tme = date("Y-m-j H:i:s",time()-60);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM \`PM_TABLE\` WHERE \`date\` <= \"$time\";") OR die(mysql_error());

Comment: Could you also show a few rows that you are expecting to be deleted please ?

Answer (score 5):

The PHP variable is getting injected as a string, without single quotes to delimit it for SQL to interpret it correctly.  But you don't need the PHP function - use:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM PM_TABLE 
              WHERE date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND");
```

Comment: yeah , thanks and I know that NOW()  but it was not working either way. Its really odd why it can't delete the record.

Comment: @Mac Taylor: You'll have to post the CREATE TABLE statement for the `PM_TABLE` - that, or you don't have the data to delete.

Comment: Nah , I'm sure about table content , when I'm saying its not deleting the record , so I meant the record exists !!! . but I update my topic with the table schema